# Azure CDN high max latency

Tags: azure, blazor-webassembly, azure-cdn

We are experimenting with using blazor webasembly with angular. It works nicely, but blazor requires a lot of dlls to be loaded,  so we decided to store them in azure blob storage, and to serve it we use microsoft CDN on azure.

When we check average latency as users started working, it shows values between 200-400 ms. But max values of latency jump to 5-6 minutes.

This happens for our ussual workload 1k-2k users over course of 1 hour. If they dont have blazor files cached locally yet that can be over 60 files per user requested from cdn.

My question is if this is expected behaviour or we can have some bad configuration somewhere.

I mention blazor WS just in case, not sure it can be problem specificaly with way how these files are loaded, or it is only because it is big amount of fetched files.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

I did check if files are  served from cache, and from response headers it seems so: `x-cache: TCP_HIT`. Also Byte Hit ratio from cdn profile seem ok,mostly 100% and it never falls under 65%.

Comment: In your Azure CDN profile, what have you set for `Cache expiration duration`, `Caching behavior` in the Caching rules blade?

Comment: Only thing i can set in Caching rules is query string caching behavior. If i read docs correctly, this can be set only with Azure CDN Standard from Verizon and Azure CDN Standard from Akamai.  Threre is no max-age set on the origin either (blob storage).